# i am having a problem with playing an audio blob i get from a microphone. it works for the first time but doesnt seem to work after that

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, html5-audio, web-mediarecorder

i am trying to add a voice message feature to my chat app and i have a problem on playing the audio that i record.

**recordAudio.js**

```
import { onUnmounted } from 'vue'
const constraint = { audio: true }
let chunks = []

function record() {

    let mediaRecorder
    let stream

    function close() {
        // console.log(mediaRecorder?.state, 'state man')
        if (mediaRecorder && mediaRecorder?.state == 'recording'){
            mediaRecorder?.stop()
            stream && (
                stream.getTracks()
                    .forEach(track => track.stop())
            )
        }
    }

    onUnmounted(() => {
        close()
    })

    async function start() {
        if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            const strm = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraint)

            // console.log(strm)
            if (!strm) return false

            // console.log('media', mediaRecorder)
            stream = strm
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(strm)
            
            mediaRecorder.start(100)

            // console.log('listingin for audio')
            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => {
                // console.log(e.data)
                chunks.push(e.data)
            }
        }

        return true
    }

    function stop() {
        close()
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
        console.log(chunks)
    chunks = []
    // const audioURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

    return blob
    }

    return {
        start,
        stop
    }
}

export {
    record
}
```

**this is a code fragment in a .vue file**

```
import {record} from '@util/recordAudio.js'
const { start, stop } = record()

async function recordAudio() {
  if (!recording.value) {
    let res = await start()
    res && (recording.value = true)
  } else {
    stop()
    recording.value = false
  }
}

function sendAudio() {
    let audioBlob = stop()
    recording.value = false
    console.log(audioBlob)
    messages.addMessage({
        id: props.chat.id,
        message: {
          id: 1,
          to: 2,
          from: 1,
          message: audioBlob,
          seen: true,
          type: 'audio',
          createdAt: new Date()
        }
    })
}

let url = {}
function getObjectUrl(id, message) {
    if (!url[id]) {
        url[id] = URL.createObjectURL(message)
        return url[id]
    }
    return url[id]
}

//this is the template for the audio
<div v-if='message.type == "audio"'>
  <audio controls :src='getObjectUrl(message.id, message.message)'></audio>
</div>
```

it seems to work for the first time and it doesnt work after.
in firefox i get the warning/error

- Media resource blob:http://localhost:5374/861d13c5-533f-4cd7-8608-68eecc7deb4e could not be decoded
- Media resource blob:http://localhost:5374/861d13c5-533f-4cd7-8608-68eecc7deb4e could not be decoded, error: Error Code: NS_ERROR_DOM_MEDIA_METADATA_ERR (0x806e0006)
  [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvibx.png)

Comment: As a guess, it seems to have problems recognizing the audio format. Do you know which format the recording is in, is it really OGG, as you seem to assume? Or MP3, WAV,, etc..? With the audio element you can set the source media type. Try it with the correct type, to see whether this helps: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source

Comment: hey thank you for your comment. nothing seems to be working for me so i have decided to drop this approach and go with AudioContext and mp3 encoder(lamejs) which seems to work for now.